# how to leave out the first tab when uploading xlsx file to jupyter notebook using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to load in an xlsx file to Jupyter Notebook using Pandas. The xlsx file has many tabs that are named with numbering conventions (such as 34567). The numbering conventions will also be different depending on the file. The only issue I am having is finding a way to upload the xlsx file into Jupyter notebook but have it leave out the first tab since it is not needed. An example of my code: `CTN = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Folder\CTN.xlsx', sheet_name = None, skipfooter = 1), ignore_index = True)`

What I am currently doing is just opening the xlsx file and deleting off the first tab but these files are big so it takes a while for Excel to open them. So, I am trying to avoid opening the file until it is uploaded into Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the sheet names except the 1st:

```
excel=pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Folder\CTN.xlsx')

sheet_names=excel.sheet_names[1:]
```

Then just read in:

```
CTN = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name = sheet_names, skipfooter = 1), ignore_index = True)
```